# Localization in ASP.NET Core using VS Code - "No resources found"

Tags: c#, localization, resources, resource-files, asp.net-core-localization

I'm trying to implement localization in my ASP.NET Core application using **VS Code**, but I keep getting **"No resources found = true"**. I've double-checked my implementation and I'm pretty sure everything is set up correctly, but I can't figure out what's causing this.

Here's what I've done so far:

I've added the **Microsoft.Extensions.Localization** package to my project.
I've created a **Resources **folder with a **x.en-US.resx** file in it for my default language (English).
I've created a x.fr-FR.resx file in the same folder for French translations.
I Use** ResX Editor** Extension to create resx files.
In my Program.cs file, I've added the following lines of code to configure localization:

```
builder.services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

var supportedCultures = new[]
{
    new CultureInfo("en-US"),
    new CultureInfo("fr-FR"),
};
var options = new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US"),
    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
};

app.UseRequestLocalization(options);
```

In my controller, I'm using the IstringLocalizer to translate my localized strings, like this:

```
 private readonly IStringLocalizer<WeatherForecastController> _localizer;

    public WeatherForecastController(IStringLocalizer<WeatherForecastController> localizer)
    {
        _localizer = localizer;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
       return Ok(_localizer["Key"]) ;
    }
```

i have added the key and its value to resix file

Despite all this, I still get the "No resources found". Can anyone point me in the right direction to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like your naming is off. The path or name of the resx files must match the namespace of the type given as type argument to `IStringLocalizer<T>`.
Assuming your class and resx files aren't actually named 'x', both these naming conventions/folder structures will work.

```bash
Resources/
├── Controllers.WeatherForecastController.en-US.resx
└── Controllers.WeatherForecastController.fr-FR.resx
```

or

```bash
Resources/
└── Controllers
    ├── WeatherForecastController.en-US.resx
    └── WeatherForecastController.fr-FR.resx
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. I wanted to apologize for the confusion in my original question. I named my class and its constructor 'x' for simplicity, but forgot to update the parameter name in IStringLocalizer. Your solution for naming conventions for my resource files, and your advice on folder structures for files was very useful.
I'm sorry to say that I don't have enough reputation to vote up your answer, but I wanted to let you know that I completely accept your answer. It was a very good and complete answer that helped me solve my problem.
Thank you again for your assistance."